# C# Хранение генерируемых запросов к БД

Tags: c#

У меня есть некие шаблоны отчётов , в которых посредством запросов к БД подсчитывается нужные поля . С хранением данных проблем нет , но вот как можно например сохранить Linq  запрос , т.е сериализовать его ??? Пока приходит в голову мысль использовать текстовые запросы , но это плохо

Comment: Зачем сериализовывать LINQ запросы? Не проще тогда SQL сохранить?

Comment: Скорее всего вы используете набор параметров, которые подставляете в запрос, и которые определяют набор данных. Возможно даже это некий объект, группирующий эти параметры. на мой взгляд именно его и нужно сериализовать

Comment: Запросы используются многократно, и к разным данным , поэтому ответ morphey83 более логичным кажется, но тогда придется нехило постараться ,чтобы воспроизвести их

Comment: Э-э... Вы вполне можете хранить linq-запросы в переменных/коллекциях. Или вам в файл его сохранить нужно?

Comment: Написал же сериализовать , в файл конечно

Comment: _нехило постараться_ - с чего бы? Вот у вас есть несколько параметров, которые вы используете при запросе в некотором методе.. Сохраняете их в файл любым удобным образом. Потом считываете и просто вызываете тот метод с этими параметрами.

Comment: А если таких параметров больше 130?))) И запросы всегда уникальные для каждого шаблона ?))

Comment: У метода больше 130 параметров? | Ну так при тех же параметрах будет получаться тот же самый запрос. Если, конечно, у вас нет глобальных переменных и сайд-эффектов.

Answer (score 0):

если ты используешь Entity Framework Core, такое уже придумали
вот так сохраняют запрос:

```
делегат = EF.CompileQuery((параметры) => выражения_LINQ)
```

потом подставляешь в делегат свои переменные 'параметры'

```
private static Func<ApplicationContext, int, User> userById =
        EF.CompileQuery((ApplicationContext db, int id) => 
                db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id));
//подставляем параметры
User u = userById(db, 1);
```

Comment: А этот UserById сериализуется на диск ?)) Про скомпилированный запрос я знаю, но можно или нет их реально сохранить на диск